# Error haciendo cURL en PowerShell

Tags: post, curl

Ejecuto este comando en la power shell de windows 10 y me da error.

> curl --data '{"method":"web3_sha3","params":["0xe80966bc0e85e3e00bf7a2b6526aea7e8ecf4e0b"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:22000

[image: reu]

**EDIT**
He cambiado el content-type a application/x-www-form-urlencoded y me sigue dando error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

Comment: @JackNavaRow el problema persiste

Comment: verifica que acepta tu backend, probablemente no acepta ese tipo de cabeceras, puedes probar con POSTMAN, y la estructura de los PARAMs es sospechosa; intenta sin el header

Comment: Si el tema es que iba a probar con POSTMAN pero no se cuales son los nombres de los parametros que tengo que pasar.

Comment: oh disculpa powershell tiene su [propio comando](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-RestMethod?view=powershell-5.1)